# What is the report desinger/builder option for ASP.NET CORE 3.1 and Blazor?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, report

We were using RDLC report for ASP.NET MVC.

It is not supporting anymore!

What should we use for report builder/designer

1. Blazor view
2. ASP.NET CORE MVC
3. Other SPA Library like (Angular, React...)

Comment: As mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/22304), currently ASP.NET Core team seems no plan to support it. You can search for and try some third party web reporting tools.

Comment: which one do you think? Open source?

Comment: As far as I know, most of third party reporting viewer tools are not open source and not free:-(

Comment: can you recommend most suitable for RDLC alternative, or is there any HTML designer template tool

Comment: `can you recommend most suitable for RDLC alternative, or is there any HTML designer template tool ` In [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/1528), community members shared some alternative, you can try it. Besides, I recommend that you can search about "reportviewer in asp.net core" with your favorite search engine to find more possible approaches.